# ¿Por qué no me da el valor de ide o la lista ? y ¿ Como puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
ide = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
Amigos = {ide:['Carlos','Carl','12/11/02']}
print (ide)
ide = input('Digita el id: ')

if ide in Amigos:
    print(Amigos[ide])
```

Comment: Debe de convertir a entero la entrada: `ide = int(input('Digita el id: '))`. Además, deberá validar la entrada, porque el cast puede dar error si no se introduce un entero por consola.

Comment: Bienvenido Jesus a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando generas la variable `ide` usando `randint()` obtienes un valor entero. Cuando ingresas la variable `ide` con `input()` obtienes una **cadena**. No puedes comparar enteros con cadenas.

La solución es convertir la cadena a entero usando `int()`

```
import random
ide = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
Amigos = {ide:['Carlos','Carl','12/11/02']}
print (ide)
ide = int(input('Digita el id: '))

if ide in Amigos:
    print(Amigos[ide])
```

produce:

```
3051708
Digita el id: 3051708
['Carlos', 'Carl', '12/11/02']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

mi suposicion es que es un error de sintaxis. te sobra un espacio en blanco en el print y sus parentesis

```
import random
ide = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
Amigos = {ide:['Carlos','Carl','12/11/02']}
print (ide)      # AQUI ESTA EL PRINT DEFECTUOSO
ide = input('Digita el id: ')

if ide in Amigos:
    print(Amigos[ide])
```

la otra razon puede ser que simplemente estas ingresando un ide errado

Comment: Si no tienes certeza de la solución, o manera de demostrar que es una solución correcta, es mejor abstenerse de publicar.